# Inclusion tag error ..... Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load

Tags: django, templates, inclusion

index.html has a block containing the context from a view called init in the crudapp app.Index.html also has a block called sidebar_files which I trying to populate using an inclusion tag.
I have created an inclusion tag in fileuploader/templatetags/fileuploader_tags.py,

```
from django.db import models
from .models import FileModel
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('sidebar_files.html')
def file_sharing_sidebar():
    file_model = FileModel.objects.all().reverse()
    return {'file_model': file_model}
```

Also that directiory does contain an empty **inti**.py file (using double underscores).
In the project template files I have the sidebar_files.html with the load tags,

```
{% load fileuploader_tags %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% for item in file_model %}
      .... blah .....
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The app is included in INSTALLED_APPS. 
My main index.html file used the fileuploader_tag and tries to use the sidebar_file.html template like this,

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load fileuploader_tags %}
......
{% block sidebar %} {% file_sharing_sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

I have restarted the dev server. The error I get is,

> Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to
>   load 'fileuploader.templatetags.fileuploader_tags': No module named
>   models

and specifically mentions this line from crudapp/view.py

> return render(request, 'forum.html', context)

and is specific to the main view called 'init' which sends its context to forum.html. This template is a block in index.html. Here is the 'init' view,

```
def init(request):
    postModel = list(PostModel.objects.raw('SELECT *, max(pub_date), count(topic_id) AS freq, count(DISTINCT author) AS contributors FROM crudapp_postmodel GROUP BY topic_id ORDER BY pub_date DESC'))
    paginator = Paginator(postModel, 8)
    page2 = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        forum_model = paginator.page(page2)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        forum_model = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        forum_model = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    blogModel = BlogModel.objects.all().order_by('pub_date').reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(blogModel, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('blog')
    try:
        blog_model = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        blog_model = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        blog_model = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # context = {'blog_model': blog_model}

    totalposts = PostModel.objects.annotate(Count('post'))
    totalusers = User.objects.annotate(Count('id'))
    totalfiles = FileModel.objects.filter(approved=True).annotate(Count('upload'))
    totalarticles = BlogModel.objects.filter(approved=True).annotate(Count('article'))
    totalviews = TopicModel.objects.aggregate(numviews = Sum('views'))
    # If there are topis with no posts the number of topics below will still be correct
    totaltopics = PostModel.objects.aggregate(numtopics = Count('topic__id', distinct=True))
    context = {'blog_model': blog_model, 'forum_model': forum_model, 'current_time':   timezone.now(), 'totalarticles': totalarticles, 'totalfiles': totalfiles, 'totalposts': totalposts, 'totaltopics': totaltopics, 'totalusers': totalusers, 'totalviews': totalviews}
    return render(request, 'forum.html', context)
```

I have used the inclusion tag before once, successfully, but can't get it to work here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error suggests, Python is failing to find a `models` module. The problem is this line in your `fileuploader_tags.py`:

```
from .models import FileModel
```

Which will try to look for a `models.py` *in the same directory as the current file*. Change it to:

```
from fileuploader.models import FileModel
```

(This assumes your app is called `fileuploader`).

or, to use a relative path, assuming `models.py` is located in the same directory as `templatetags/`:

```
from ..models import FileModel
```